# Persist the custom header in ResponseHeader

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, response-headers

I have all my MVC controllers inheriting from a base controller and it has a method which adds my required header in the response header:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{    
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("AdditionaInfo", Environment.MachineName);
}
```

This works fine on my local environment but I don't see this header in response once I deploy it to Azure.

I can see other standard headers in the response like:

> Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
>
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Length: 122 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Date:  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=300
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
>
> X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

It's just my header is missing in the response.

Do I need to configure something in Azure? Or is it the way adding header which causes the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider moving the code to Middleware rather than a filter (which is where I assume you are doing it based on the `OnActionExecuted` method name).

You can do this in a simple way in `startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // other code here

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("AdditionalInfo", Environment.MachineName);
        await next.Invoke();
    });

    // additional code here

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right I am doing it in a filter. I will try this and let you know if it works for me. Thanks.